# How to automatically save structural variable with same name of load name like "save as.."

Tags: matlab, save

When I load file with name "11_15_2016_12_46" which is in workspace structural variable with name Struct, how could I save the variable with the name of load file automatically? I try some `save` function, but it doesn't work. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

'11_15_2016_12_46' is illegal variable name.

Add some prefix letter.

```
Filename='11_15_2016_12_46';
NewVarName=['S',Filename];
eval([NewVarName,'=MyStruct'])
save(Filename,'-struct', NewVarName)
SavedData=load(Filename);
disp(NewFileData)
```

You can also try something else, new struct with dynamic fieldname:

```
Filename='11_15_2016_12_46';
fieldname=['S',Filename];
NewStruct.(fieldname)=MyStruct;
save(Filename,'-struct', 'NewStruct')
SavedData2=load(Filename);
```